# Need to preform operation in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to subtract 2 values, and do the calculation instantly with javascript.
I need to find a way to target second `<select>` id in JS, since i echo the options, I do it like this:

```
<tr> <!-- first row, with css -->
<td style="width:50%;">From</td>
<td style="width:50%;">
    <select name="fromlevel" id="fromlevel" style="width:100%; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">
        <?php 
        $i = 1;
        while ($i < 91) {
            echo '
            <option value=f' . $i . ' name=f' . $i . '>' . $i . '</option>';
            $i++;
        }
        ?>  
    </select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr> <!-- second row, with css -->
<td>To</td>
<td>
    <select name="tolevel" id="tolevel" style="width:100%; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">
        <?php 
        $i = 1;

        while ($i < 91) {
            echo '
            <option value=t' . $i . ' name=t' . $i . '>' . $i . '</option>';
            $i++;
        }
        ?>  
    </select>
</td>
</tr>
```

I referenced the IDs with f1, f2, f3, f4 etc, and t1, t2, t3, t4 etc. Hhow do i distinguish between them in JS?

The JS below works if I just refernce the ID of the first `<select>` as $i, im very bad with JS, and i dont know how to make that reference f$i

```
var level_current_prices = {};

for(var i = 1; i <= 90; i++ ) {
   level_current_prices[i] = i;
}

function getCurrentLevel() { // current level, from
    var levelSetPrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["priceCalcForm"];
    var selectedLevel = theForm.elements["fromlevel"];
    levelSetPrice = level_current_prices[selectedLevel.value];
    return levelSetPrice;
}

function calculateTotal() {
    var LevelPrice = getCurrentLevel();
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price For the Leveling $"+LevelPrice;
}

function hideTotal() {
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='none';
}

document.forms['priceCalcForm'].fromlevel.onchange = function () {
   calculateTotal();
}
```

Comment: I do not completely understand what you want to do, but have you tried `theForm.elements["tolevel"]`? which refrences the second select.

Comment: not a solution, but you should really quote your html attributes eg: `<option value="t1" name="t1">Caption</option>`

Answer (score 0):

Little confused by your question. I think you're talking about the following lines?

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 90; i++ ) {
   level_current_prices[i] = i;
}
```

Pre-filling the object with data, the index for `level_current_prices` is a string, not a number (that would be an array). You can do what you want inside the brackets pretty much to generate a key however all you need is `level_current_prices['f'+i]`

Please clarify your question if this isn't what you mean.

If it is what you wanted you could pre-generate the object (as JSON) using php.

```
<?php
  $i=1;
  $out = "{";
  while ($i<91) {
    $out .= "\"t".$i."\"=".$i.",";
    $i++;
  }
  $out .="};";
  echo "var level_current_prices = ".$out;
?>
```

It's been a while since i've use php so you might be able to do it better :D.

Comment: You can "use" numbers as property names for objects in JavaScript, they just get type-coerced into strings. `myObj[1]` and `myObj['1']` end up referring to the same property. It is good to point out, however, that using only sequential numbers as property values in your object means that you can indeed probably just get away with an array.